# Position link by ID below a sticky menu

Tags: html, hyperlink

In our online store, there is a sticky top menu. I would like to send a link to a section to my clients `www.onlinestore.com/#section`, but when defining the link by the id, the link leads to the corresponding section but its header is hidden behind the sticky menu. Is there a solution so that the section link goes just below the menu?

[image]

Comment: We can't possibly help you without code. Please provide a [MCVE]. There a many ways you may have implemented this, don't make us guess which one it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an invisible pseudo element to the original target element of the link via CSS, like this:

```
#your_anchor_id::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -90px; 
  height: 90px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will "extend" the element with that ID so that the anchor will be 90px above the main element (adjust value as needed), without causing any other visible changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can just adjust padding-top property of your section to solve that. Your link leads to corresponding section but since your menu is big its covering header. With adjusting padding-top you should be able to see your header.

If you don't want to modify page layout then you can add this just before your section:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
   <div id="#section" style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      transform: translateY(-50px);"></div>
</div>
```

With this you can just adjust transform property so that your header is not covered by menu, this will not be visible on your page but will solve problem you are facing.

Comment: Thank you. Defining wide margins between sections is not the solution I am looking for, we are not interested in modifying the layout of the page

Comment: I just added additional solution in my answer, this should solve it without modifying the layout of the page.